# Convert key value pair strings in a list to columns in a Data Frame Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list which has the following:

["ID : 1234 Name: John Exam Code:5678",
"ID : 4566 Name: Jack Learning Code: 5678",
"ID : 5678 Name: Helen Exam Code: 5435"]

Each item in the list have same headers like "ID" and "Name" but some have "Exam Code" and Others have "Learning Code"

How do I convert it into a DataFrame which shows me the following output:

| ID | Name | Exam Code | Learning Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John | 5678 |  |
| 4566 | Jack |  | 5678 |
| 5678 | Helen | 5435 |  |

UPDATED QUERY:

Apologies, Some of the data may also have first name and last name
e.g
["ID : 1234 Name: John Black Exam Code:5678",
"ID : 4566 Name: Jack Learning Code: 5678",
"ID : 5678 Name: Helen Exam Code: 5435"]

SO how can we deal with this ?

| ID | Name | Exam Code | Learning Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Black | 5678 |  |
| 4566 | Jack |  | 5678 |
| 5678 | Helen | 5435 |  |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Parsing the strings in the list items would be a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module to parse the data. For example:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    "ID : 1234 Name: John Exam Code:5678",
    "ID : 4566 Name: Jack Learning Code: 5678",
    "ID : 5678 Name: Helen Exam Code: 5435",
]

data = []
for line in lst:
    data.append(
        dict(
            re.findall(
                r"(ID|Name|Exam Code|Learning Code)\s*:\s*([^\s]+)", line
            )
        )
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data).fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ID   Name Exam Code Learning Code
0  1234   John      5678              
1  4566   Jack                    5678
2  5678  Helen      5435
```

---

EDIT: To add surnames:

```py
lst = [
    "ID : 1234 Name: John Black Exam Code:5678",
    "ID : 4566 Name: Jack Learning Code: 5678",
    "ID : 5678 Name: Helen Exam Code: 5435",
]

data = []
for line in lst:
    id_ = re.search(r"(ID)\s*:\s*(\d+)", line)
    name = re.search(r"(Name)\s*:\s*(.*)\s+(?:Exam|Learning)", line)
    code = re.search(r"(Exam Code|Learning Code)\s*:\s*(.*)", line)
    data.append(dict([id_.groups(), name.groups(), code.groups()]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data).fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ID        Name Exam Code Learning Code
0  1234  John Black      5678              
1  4566        Jack                    5678
2  5678       Helen      5435
```

Comment: Just a last query, I am a begginer with regular experssion, what exp. should be used if there is a first name and a last name ?

Comment: @manosubron Can you give an example? Edit your question and put it there.

Comment: have added. Thanks